# HTML img src not updating dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, electron

In a section of my [desktop app](https://github.com/jadech32/mirrortest), I've written a function which updates/rewrites the html div text and an image source depending on the output of a json file (which changes), however the img src is not changing along with it.

What the app looks [like](https://image.prntscr.com/image/PNBfm-pQQ7KWnVq5HfG2Fw.png). The 'logo' image should change when the text (news headlines) changes.

Here's the part of the [function](https://github.com/jadech32/mirrortest/blob/master/js/scripts.js):

```
function newsAPI(){
  for(i = 0; i<config['newsapi']['sources'].length;i++) {
    document.getElementById('news_icon').src="img/news/" + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + ".png";
    request({
      url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + '&sortBy=top&apiKey=' + config['newsapi']['api_key'],
      method: 'get'
    }, function (err, res, body){
      var parsedbody = JSON.parse(body)
      parsedbody = parsedbody['articles'];
      document.getElementById('news_1').innerHTML = parsedbody[0]['title'];
      document.getElementById('news_2').innerHTML = parsedbody[1]['title'];
      document.getElementById('news_3').innerHTML = parsedbody[2]['title'];
      document.getElementById('news_4').innerHTML = parsedbody[3]['title'];
      document.getElementById('news_5').innerHTML = parsedbody[4]['title'];

    })
      sleep(10000);
  }
}
```

This function fetches news headlines as json data from an API. `config['newsapi']['sources'][i]` matches the names of the images in the directory (config['newsapi']['sources'] is a list)

Here is the relevant part of HTML:

```
    <div id="img" class ="image"></div>
    <img id="news_icon" class="news_head" />
    <div id="news_1" class ="news"></div>
    <div id="news_2" class ="news"></div>
```

My sleep function:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: We don't want/need to see all this code. Include only the relevant parts of the code or go for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How many `config['newsapi']['sources']` are there?

Comment: Please get your JS code back, as it was relevant.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, I've edited the code now. `config['newsapi']['sources']` is a list (so no. of elements is arbitrary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has to be with this line:

```
document.getElementById('news_icon').src="img/news/" + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + ".png";
```

Add `console.log(config['newsapi']['sources'][i]);` before that line and check the output.

Check the following:

- Maybe `config['newsapi']['sources']` has no string or wrong path.
- Or the string is something like this "bbc.png", which means the "src" attribute of the image gets the value of "img/news/bbc.png.png" (double .png)
- Or the path returned has full path which results in "img/news/img/news/bbc.png"
- Or maybe the image link is correct, it's just that the image doesn't exist in that path "img/news".

**EDIT:**

What you may would like to do is 1. do a request to the server, 2. then wait 10 seconds.

Your code will not work as expected because request is an async function, meaning it will not wait for the sleep function.

Here's how to do it with async functions. I put your iteration code inside a `setTimeout` function:

```
function newsAPI() {
    for(i = 0; i<config['newsapi']['sources'].length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('news_icon').src = "img/news/" + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + ".png";
            request({
                url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + '&sortBy=top&apiKey=' + config['newsapi']['api_key'],
                method: 'get'
                }, function (err, res, body){
                    var parsedbody = JSON.parse(body)
                    parsedbody = parsedbody['articles'];
                    document.getElementById('news_1').innerHTML = parsedbody[0]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_2').innerHTML = parsedbody[1]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_3').innerHTML = parsedbody[2]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_4').innerHTML = parsedbody[3]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_5').innerHTML = parsedbody[4]['title'];
                });
        }, 10000 * i);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
function newsAPI() {
    for(i = 0; i<config['newsapi']['sources'].length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('news_icon').src = "img/news/" + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + ".png";
            request({
                url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + '&sortBy=top&apiKey=' + config['newsapi']['api_key'],
                method: 'get'
                }, function (err, res, body){
                    var parsedbody = JSON.parse(body)
                    parsedbody = parsedbody['articles'];
                    document.getElementById('news_1').innerHTML = parsedbody[0]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_2').innerHTML = parsedbody[1]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_3').innerHTML = parsedbody[2]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_4').innerHTML = parsedbody[3]['title'];
                    document.getElementById('news_5').innerHTML = parsedbody[4]['title'];
                    if(i+1 == config['newsapi']['sources'].length) {// if is last iteration, repeat again
                        setTimeout(newsAPI, 10000);
                    }
                });
        }, 10000 * i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I've added print statements to step through the loop. It just spits out every iteration and then sleeps at the very end when the loop finishes... this is very weird.

Comment: @JC1 I don't find it weird. Comment out or remove `sleep(10000)` and see what happens

Comment: The for loop prints in the correct order, but the sleeping happens after the entire for loop has finished. I think this is the problem

Comment: @JC1 `request` function is asynchronized, meaning it will not wait for the sleep function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It works now, with some changes (declaring the anonymous function so that it can use the counter variable)

Comment: how would I keep looping infinitely without breaking it (i.e. going back to the start of the `config['newsapi']['sources']` array)? Using an infinite while loop does not work.

Comment: @JC1 That's up to your logic and can be done by many ways. Added **EDIT2** in my answer, which simply have an additional if condition to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Had this happen to me this past week,

Try this

```
document.getElementById('news_icon').src="img/news/" + config['newsapi']['sources'][i] + new Date().getTime() + ".png";
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. The img tag is updating, but the src is not changing from the first one.